# Python unittest test case

Tags: python, oop, python-unittest

Please help! (Unittest python)

For example, i have a file call happy.py, i create

```
class Happy:

    def read_file(self, file_name):

    ...............

    file.close()
```

for the read_file before close, I Insert the text into the self.text_lines and remove whitespaces from the end of the line

unittest is below the class Happy.
I wanted to use the unittest to check whether is my answer for the read_file is equal to the real answer or not

```
class TestHappy(unittest.TestCase):

     def test_read_filename(self):
```

After this what should I write? as I have to read file name abc.txt and see if the text is equal to ['Hi', 'Happy', 'Hello"]

abc.txt:
Hi 
Happy
Hello

Comment: And your question is? Please include a [mre] with the code as text directly in the question, do not link to a picture of your code.

Comment: So your unittest fails - without seeing the tested code we can't say anything more, please add a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to decide what `read_file` *does*. Let's assume something simple: it just reads the contents of its argument, and returns a list of lines.

You can write the tests before you actually write the method:

```
class TestHappy(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_read_filename(self):
        h = Happy()
        self.assertEquals(h.read_file("foo.txt"), ["Hi", "Happy", "Hello"])
```

If you run the test before you write the method, it obviously fails. The idea behind test-driven development is that a failing test is your *starting* point: you start editing your code and running your tests until the test *passes*.

Comment: I'm curious if anyone is really living up to the concept of TDD during development. Anyways it is ideal. Upvoted :)